using groupby in conditional form in python
I have a df of people with their name and age and sex and other things.
I need to count number of people in each 10 years range.
for example i need to know how many women are in 0-10, 10-20, 20-30  till 90-100.
I use this code:
for i in range(0,10):
    n = '{} - {}'.format(i*10, i*10+9)
    m = train_data.groupby("Age").apply(lambda x: x in (i*10, i*10+9)).count()
    print(n,m)

but it doesn't work.

You can use df.cut(), create labels and bins, then apply groupby():
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
    'Age': [23, 45, 56, 67, 34, 89, 12, 78, 79, 75, 72],
    'Sex': ['F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
labels = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '90-99']

df['Age Group'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
res = df.groupby(['Age Group', 'Sex']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(res)


Prints
Sex        F  M
Age Group      
0-9        0  0
10-19      1  0
20-29      1  0
30-39      1  0
40-49      0  1
50-59      0  1
60-69      0  1
70-79      4  0
80-89      0  1
90-99      0  0


As @user24714692 pointed out, you can use pd.cut to bin your ages. You can also use pd.crosstab to create the crosstabulation of these resultant variables:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
    'Age':  [23,  45,  56,  67,  34,  89,  12,  78,  79,  75,  72 ],
    'Sex':  ['F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
})

bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
labels = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '90-99']

res = pd.crosstab(
    index=pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False), 
    columns=df['Sex'], 
    dropna=False,
)

print(res)
# Sex    F  M
# Age
# 0-9    0  0
# 10-19  1  0
# 20-29  1  0
# 30-39  1  0
# 40-49  0  1
# 50-59  0  1
# 60-69  0  1
# 70-79  4  0
# 80-89  0  1
# 90-99  0  0

